External Credential Principal Access is not included in managed package permission set metadata
We have a managed package that includes one permission set.
We have used the Salesforce Setup UI to include in the permission set an External Credential Principal Access assignment. However, this is not reflected when we retrieve the permission set metadata.
Is that working as designed? I mean, are permission sets not meant to stored assignment of External Credential Principal Access?

It works for me.  In my permission set I have a externalCredentialPrincipalAccesses that references my external credential.  have you checked the api version of your manifest and sfdx-project.json  file?

@NickC can you please share your metadata? and what's your API version?

As Nick pointed out, this seems to be an API version issue. I was using version 58.0 and when I switched to 60.0 the retrieval of the permission set included the External Credential Principal Access I was expecting.
This issue was documented in an idea page (where I was also able to see the actual metadata elements):
https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000PG3baUAD/external-credential-principal-access-deployment
